# Silverlight User Experience URL Image Displays?

Tags: silverlight, user-experience

I have a database that contains a table for storing URL Images (since storing the images as byte arrays could potentially slow the DB down massively). There are two fields in the image table, one that stores a URL to a low resolution image and one that stores a URL to a high Resolution image. So far this is just a concept and has not been fully implemented.

My question is, if i want to pull back these images via the database URL's to display in a Silverlight View, what is the best method of going about doing this and where on the web should I store the images? - On a personal web server?

Following this I want an awesome user experience for the image display. Potentially a thumbnail which when hovered over grows slightly and when clicks zooms to a bit lightbox display.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I ask what you edited? I always see this and never know whats been changed...

Comment: Click on the date after "edited" to see the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickest way that will allow you to retain any existing Images directories and organization, and keep them out of your XAP.

```
 string src = Application.Current.Host.Source.ToString();
 string applicationRoot = src.Substring(0, src.IndexOf("ClientBin"));
 //Where CLientBin is the location of your XAP file
 string imageURL = applicationRoot + "Images/MyImage.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to **add the images to your Silverlight application** and then reference them using relative paths.  Set the *Build Action* to "Resource" and *Copy to Output Directory* to "False".  This will embed the image into your Silverlight application.  Great for simplicity and performance, but not so great if you have large, plentiful, or constantly changing images.

```
<Image Source="Images/LoRes/10001.JPG" />
```

Another approach would be to **deploy the images to the same web server** that is hosting your XAP file.  Using this approach, you can still reference the images by a relative path, only now the path is relative to the XAP, instead of the application root folder.

```
<Image Source="../Images/LoRes/10001.JPG" />
```

Silverlight also supports absolute URLs so you could **deploy to a different web server** entirely if you like.

```
<Image Source="http://myimages.com/Images/LoRes/10001.JPG" />
```

If the database only has image names, and you are doing data-binding, you can write a converter to take the image name and come up with the relative or absolute hyperlink.

The [MSDN documentation for the Image class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image(VS.95).aspx?PHPSESSID=ev0v34i8u80gkmn37sd8r65363) has more information.